# Is it possible to initialize Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService off line? - with refresh token

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I need to get the folders from Google Drive, I already passed authorization and have the Refresh token.
Is there a way to initialize the DriveService without authorize again?
I write my code in vb

Comment: yes. A refresh token is all about offline access and there is no need to authorize again.

Comment: Great, so how do I do that?  I cannot find any place in the net an intialization of DriveService with Refresh token